# Get Datalist label in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, label, datalist

Hi I have a datalist as follows:

```
<asp:DataList CssClass="courseNameInfo" ID="CourseData" runat="server" DataSourceID="CourseNameSQL">
                <ItemTemplate>
                 <strong> Course Name:</strong><br /> 
                    <asp:Label ID="CourseLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Course") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

I am trying to gt the labels value into my download button click event, This is what I tried:

```
 Label lbl = (Label)CourseData.Items[0].FindControl("CourseLabel");
```

However, I am getting an error message saying:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to
>   System.Reflection.Emit.Label

How would I get the label any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The namespace of `Label` is probably wrong.  Check your using directives

Comment: What should be the using statement assigned so it would stop causing the issue then?

Comment: using System.Web.UI.WebControls; instead of using System.Reflection.Emit; solved the issue

Comment: Your error tells you what the problem is.  You are trying to convert a `System.Web.UI.Control` to a `System.Reflection.Emit.Label`.  You aren't doing anything with reflection here (at least from the code you have posted) so that using directive is likely wrong

Answer (score 0):

wrong `using` directives:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

instead of

```
using System.Reflection.Emit;
```